# Serializing to namedtuple raises "too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I would like to use Serializer to validate and deserialize JSON.

I've tried:

```
Candidate = namedtuple("Candidate",
    ["name", "description"]
)

class CandidateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.CharField()

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return Candidate(**data)
```

And then in the repl :

```
>>> s = CandidateSerializer(data={'name': "Seb", 'description':"Hello"})
>>> s.is_valid()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 236, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 436, in run_validation
    self.run_validators(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 465, in run_validators
    to_validate.update(value)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how you use a serializer. A serializer is for taking JSON and converting to Python data types. If you then want to take the converted data and output something like a namedtuple, you'd need to implement `create()` and call it via `save()`. So:

```
class CandidateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.CharField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Candidate(**validated_data)
```

Now:

```
>>> s = CandidateSerializer(data={'name': "Seb", 'description':"Hello"})
>>> s.is_valid()
True
>>> s.save()
Candidate(name='Seb', description='Hello')
```